# Como remover os efeitos da navbar do Materialize?

Tags: html, css, front-end, materialize

Eu estava desenvolvendo um site sem a utilização do Materialize. Decidi importá-lo para usar uma de suas funcionaliaddes ([Cards](https://materializecss.com/cards.html)). Ao fazer isso, a navbar, que já tinha suas próprias características bem definidas, ficou 'corrompida' com os efeitos padrões da navbar do materialize (os quais são instanciados automaticamente ao utilizar a tag `<nav>`.

Como remover tais efeitos sem quebrar as demais funcionalidades do materialize?

Só para exemplificação:
Antes de importar o materialize era assim: 
[image]

Após importar o Materialize: [image]

Comment: Precisava de um [MCVE] para lhe responder com certeza, pois pode ser o caso de apenas usar a classe auxiliar [`.browser-default`](https://materializecss.com/helpers.html#browser-default) no seu `navbar` ou então aplicar a classe [.no-autoinit](https://materializecss.com/auto-init.html) para pular a inicialização do elemento.

Comment: Eu fiz todo o meu código de estilização da navbar utilizando apenas html + css, não há nenhum detalhe específico a respeito disso. Pense apenas em uma nav bar estilizada com um efeito qualquer, e que tal efeito foi sobreposto por características do materialize. Me fale, por favor, como utilizar essa classe .browser-default. Eu li sobre ela, mas não entendi direito como aplicá-la.

Comment: No atributo class do elemento: `class="browser-default"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode contornar a aplicação de estilos deste framework atribuindo a classe [`browser-default`](https://materializecss.com/helpers.html) para o elemento que queira reverter ao seu estado original e em seguida atribuir uma classe para esse elemento onde serão resetados todos os estilos para esse elemento e seus descendentes usando a propriedade atalho [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) passando o valor `initial`.

PS: Como você não apresentou o seu código tive que improvisar modificando esse [exemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  M.AutoInit(); //inicializa o framework
};
```

```css
/* Reseta todas as propriedades da classe nv2*/

.nv2 {
  all: initial;
}


/* Reseta todas as propriedades dos descendente de nv2*/

.nv2 * {
  all: initial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>

  <h4>The nav element</h4>

  <p>The nav element defines a set of navigation links:</p>

  <nav>
    <a href="/html/">HTML</a> |
    <a href="/css/">CSS</a> |
    <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> |
    <a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
  </nav>

  <!-- Esse nav(nv2) não será estilizado-->
  <nav class="nv2 browser-default">
    <a href="/html/">HTML</a> |
    <a href="/css/">CSS</a> |
    <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> |
    <a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso! Grato, Augusto.

Comment: Se tivesse colocado o código na pergunta seria mais fácil de descobrir o que você queria. Na próxima coloque um [mcve] para ajudar quem vai lhe ajudar.

Comment: Certamente! Foi a minha primeira pergunta aqui no SO, na próxima serei bem mais claro no que quero. De todo modo, obrigado!